# Android Native Library failed to build on different arch

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Trying to build but getting below errors .

```
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : AndroidSpUsb <= AndroidSpUsb.cpp
In file included from jni/AndroidSpUsb.cpp:18:
jni/USBEnv.h:13:10: fatal error: 'map' file not found
#include <map>
         ^~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/AndroidSpUsb/AndroidSpUsb.o] Error 1
[ERROR] --
```

Comment: did you add the include path correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I already added in my USBEnv.h    #include <map> but its not working.

Comment: add your `CMakeLists.txt` please

Comment: This libusb we r referring in our source code .  https://github.com/kuldeepdhaka/libusb/tree/android-open2

Comment: i m not good on c++ .

Comment: Typically when you see STL headers not being found, it's because you either haven't specified which STL implementation to use (or you picked the wrong one, like stlport).

Comment: Thanks for this issue has been resolved ...Thanks

Comment: Post your solution as an answer for other people that run into this problem. https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @vineetyyadav I have same issue. How can you resolve this issue?